# WordPress automatic added print page with possibility to choose copies

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So i have already 2 CPT named **ekologiska-produkter** and **f-bagare**. Each of them already have have posts about products.

I would like that a print page for each post gets added automatic. Would then take acf fields from from the original post and output them. I know how to solve everything but that part of automatic adding print page
Example http://example.com/ekologiska-produkter/produktone/print

Why i don't want to style product page/post page with css only is because:

- I will add later an button to increase quantity of that label that will print out on 1 page. So anyone can click on + and they have 2 of the same
- There will be width set and label that is supposed to print out will not be responsive on post page wich could look weird.